# Как реализовать версии css

Tags: css

Иногда замечаю такую штуку: mysite.com/style.css?v=1.0
Так вот, как же такое сделать? LESS? Или PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно GET-параметр для css и js добавляется для того, чтобы можно было обновить закэшированный файл.

Но если вам нужны именно разный текст css в зависимости от GET-параметра, то это можно реализовать как средствами php (или любого другого языка на сервере).

Для случая с Apache и PHP решение будет таким:

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   Header set Content-type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>
```

и в style.css

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css')
    ...
```

Также можно эту задачу решить и средствами web-севрера. Для nginx решение будет примерно таким:

```
location /style.css {
    if ($args ~ "v=(\d+)") {
        rewrite ^(.*) style$1?.css redirect;
    }
}
```